# UIActionsSheet text shadow problem

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, shadow

I have a problem with the text shadow of the UIActionSheet buttons. At iOS 4.0.2 long string were truncated automatically. No at iOS 4.2 these texts are presented with a smaller font. But now the offset of the shadow is corrupted and to big.

Is there a possibility to change/remove the text shadow of the UIActionSheet.
[image]

EDIT: I'm building the UIActionSheet not with `initWithTitle:`, but with the normal `init` and sets all needed properties afterwards because the number of possible buttons is dynamic and the texts cannot be change. I've tested it with `initWithTitle:` and got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952298/how-can-i-truncate-an-nsstring-to-a-set-length) to truncate your string before displaying it in a UIActionSheet.

Comment: This is not really the answer I wanted to get. Manually truncation of the strings is only the second best way.

Answer (score 1):

I can think there are two workarounds for this (although I would not them myself in my application, reason listed below the workarounds):

- In the first case you access the sublayers of UIActionSheet, get the labels, change the `shadowOffset` and `shadowColor` before presenting the actionsheet.
- Secondly you can initialize the actionsheet with blank titles and add your own labels as subviews on the actionsheet at right places. (More tricky then the first approach).

Now the first approach is very risky as the layer structure of UIActionSheet can be changed by apple in future updates, hence your application may break and would not give good results.

Continuing with second approach is good only when you can calculate the exact frames where you should put your lebels so that they look good. But in your case the number of buttons would also vary, so this approach will take a lot of time initially to get the things working.

Hence, I would go for truncating the strings before I set them as the title of buttons.

Not sure how much would this help. But I am sure that truncating strings before setting them as titles is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing anything non default for displaying the text?
If you only use `UIActionSheet-initWithTitle:…` you should write a bug report to Apple.
OR shorten the text to "Frankfurt International (FRA), DE" ;)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in 4.30. I found no way of fixing it in 4.2x.