# Get first ten characters in a string

Tags: string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm adding a notepad feature to my application, and I want to read the first ten characters of a string and use that string as the title for a cell in my table view.

I think I could use `substringFromIndex:`.

Can someone elaborate on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952298/how-can-i-truncate-an-nsstring-to-a-set-length

Comment: possible duplicate: [Truncate an NSString to a set length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952298/how-can-i-truncate-an-nsstring-to-a-set-length)

Comment: Thats truncating it. I want to extract the first 10 characters

Comment: Are you kidding? It's the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[@"1234567890" substringToIndex:6]
```

gives you 
**123456**

- **substringFromIndex** - from a given index to the end ([apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) )
- **substringToIndex**   - Returns a new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, but not including, the one at a given index ([apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html))