# iOS Objective C NSString.length not returning expected value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having the most basic of problems with an objective C method.
Based on a suggestion from:
[How can I truncate an NSString to a set length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952298/how-can-i-truncate-an-nsstring-to-a-set-length)

I am trying to write a method to return a truncated NSString.  However, it is not working.  When I send in "555" for example, the length (as shown by the variable 'test') comes back as 0.  I determined this by setting a break point after the line int test and hovering over the variables fullString and test.  Do I somehow need to dereference the pointer to fullString or some other thing?  I am a complete newbie in objective C.  Many thanks

```
-(NSString*) getTruncatedString:(NSString *) fullString {

    int test = fullString.length;
    int test2 = MIN(0,test);
    NSRange stringRangeTest = {0, MIN([@"Test" length], 20)};

    // define the range you're interested in
    NSRange stringRange = {0, MIN([fullString length], 20)};

    // adjust the range to include dependent chars
    stringRange = [fullString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:stringRange];

    // Now you can create the short string
    NSString* shortString = [_sentToBrainDisplay.text substringWithRange:stringRange];

    return shortString;

}
```

Based on comments and research, I got it working.  Thank you everyone. In case anyone is interested:

```
-(NSString*) getTruncatedString:(NSString *) fullString {

if (fullString == nil || fullString.length == 0) {
    return fullString;
}
NSLog(@"String length: %d", fullString.length);

// define the range you're interested in
NSRange stringRange = {MAX(0, (int)[fullString length]-20),MIN(20, [fullString length])};


// adjust the range to include dependent chars
stringRange = [fullString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:stringRange];

// Now you can create the short string
NSString* shortString = [fullString substringWithRange:stringRange];

return shortString;
```

}

Comment: "Do I somehow need to dereference the pointer to fullString" - Certainly not. You never dereference pointers to objects in Objective-C.

Comment: are you sure fullstring is not nil?

Comment: What is _sentToBrainDisplay.text value?

Comment: This whole function looks like a mess...

Comment: @Dave - this is somewhat confusing. Stack Overflow is not setup to answer questions in the Question blocks. You accepted Nickolay's answer below, and then you edited your question to post an answer for others. Which is it? You should remove your answer from the question and place it in an Answer block. You should explain the fix (I've looked at it twice, and its not apparent to me), and then you should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are passing `@"555"` to this method, not `"555"`.
Also, better way is to

`NSLog(@"String length: %d", fullString.length)`.

Comment: Thank you Nockolay for the comment about NSLog.  That, and Ramy's comment about _sentToBrainDisplay, led me to the problem.  I've posted solution in original question for anyone looking at this later.