# Truncate string containing emoji or unicode characters at word or character boundaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, emoji

[image: The Problem]

How can I truncate a string at a given length without annihilating a unicode character that might be smack in the middle of my length?  How can one determine the index of the beginning of a unicode character in a string so that I can avoid creating ugly strings. The square with half of an A visible is the location of another emoji character which has been truncated.

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)constructStatusAttributedStringWithRange:(CFRange)range

NSString *original = [_postDictionay objectForKey:@"message"];

NSMutableString *truncated = [NSMutableString string];

NSArray *components = [original componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

for(int x=0; x<[components count]; x++)
{
    //If the truncated string is still shorter then the range desired. (leave space for ...)
    if([truncated length]+[[components objectAtIndex:x] length]<range.length-3)
    {
        //Just checking if its the first word
        if([truncated length]==0 && x==0)
        {
            //start off the string
            [truncated appendString:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        else
        {
            //append a new word to the string
            [truncated appendFormat:@" %@",[components objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        x=[components count];
    }
}

if([truncated length]==0 || [truncated length]< range.length-20)
{
    truncated = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length-3)]];
}

[truncated appendString:@"..."];

NSMutableAttributedString *statusString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:truncated];
[statusString addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName value:[StyleSingleton streamStatusFont] range:NSMakeRange(0, [statusString length])];
[statusString addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[StyleSingleton streamStatusColor].CGColor range:NSMakeRange(0, [statusString length])];

return statusString;

}
```

**UPDATE** Thanks to the answer, was able to use one simple function for my needs!

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)constructStatusAttributedStringWithRange:(CFRange)range
{
NSString *original = [_postDictionay objectForKey:@"message"];

NSMutableString *truncated = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[original substringWithRange:[original rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length-3)]]];
[truncated appendString:@"..."];

NSMutableAttributedString *statusString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:truncated];
[statusString addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName value:[StyleSingleton streamStatusFont] range:NSMakeRange(0, [statusString length])];
[statusString addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[StyleSingleton streamStatusColor].CGColor range:NSMakeRange(0, [statusString length])];

return statusString;

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NSString` has a method `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange` that you can use to find the enclosing range in the string that contains only complete composed characters. For example

```
NSString *s =  @"";
NSRange r = [s rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

gives the range `{ 0, 2 }` because the Emoji character is stored as two UTF-16 characters (surrogate pair) in the string.

*Remark:* You could also check if you can simplify your first loop by using

```
enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock
```

with the `NSStringEnumerationByWords` option.

Answer (score 2):

"truncate a string at a given length" <-- Do you mean length as in byte length or length as in number of characters? If the latter, then a simple `substringToIndex:` will suffice (check the bounds first though). If the former, then I'm afraid you'll have to do something like:

```
NSString *TruncateString(NSString *original, NSUInteger maxBytesToRead, NSStringEncoding targetEncoding) {
    NSMutableString *truncatedString = [NSMutableString string];

    NSUInteger bytesRead = 0;
    NSUInteger charIdx = 0;

    while (bytesRead < maxBytesToRead && charIdx < [original length]) {
        NSString *character = [original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(charIdx++, 1)];

        bytesRead += [character lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:targetEncoding];

        if (bytesRead <= maxBytesToRead)
            [truncatedString appendString:character];
    }

    return truncatedString;
}
```

**EDIT:** Your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
NSString *original = [_postDictionay objectForKey:@"message"];

NSArray *characters = [[original componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

NSArray *truncatedCharacters = [characters subarrayWithRange:range];

NSString *truncated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [truncatedCharacters componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
```

Comment: I was originally using substringWithRange, and it would cut a unicode character literally in half, for lack of a better explanation.  I don't know that substringToIndex would preserve the character. Thoughts?

Comment: Just tried substringToIndex, and had the same unfortunate results as with substringWithRange

Comment: Hm…how are you creating your `NSString`? Are you sure that you specified the proper encoding when creating it?

Comment: Updated the question with an image showing the adverse behavior.  I am creating the said strings via user-input.

Comment: Umm…what exactly are you doing in the `for` loop? (It's kinda hard to read.) You're just combining the whitespace into a single space, right?

Comment: Also, what is `[truncated length]< range.length-20` for?

Comment: This is just checking for an edge case where the truncated string ends up being WAY too small i.e. you have a rediculous string input by the user which is one large word. ie: thisisonelongsentencewithoutanybreaksandwouldcausemeproblems

Comment: Ummm…interesting…why do you use a range instead of just a length?

Comment: I am using a range because that is what is returned from CoreText, although I can actually just use a length because coretext is giving me a range of text which will fit a given CTFrameSetter, always starting from the beginning of the string, which is why I only use the range.length value in this function.