# Calculate the size in bytes of a Swift String

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm trying to calculate the byte size of a `String` in Swift but I don't know the size of a single character; what is the byte size of a character?

Let's say I have a string:
`let str = "hello, world"`

I want to send that to some web service endpoint, but that endpoint only accepts strings whose size is under 32 bytes. How would I control the byte size of my string?

Comment: Seems like you might be interested in [How to shorten an NSString that might include emojis to the maximal length?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31733100)

Comment: Really interesting indeed, thanks !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It all depends on the character encoding, let's suppose UTF8:

```
let string = "abde"
let size = string.utf8.count
```

Note that not all characters have the same byte size in UTF8.
If your string is ASCII, you can assume 1 byte per character.

Comment: That would return the number of utf8 char but each of them is coded on 1 to 2 bytes, so it wouldn't give the actual size of the string, right ?

Comment: @Randy Yes, it would give the actual size of the string. If you need size of every character, ask for the size of every character separately.

Comment: All right, I get it, thanks a lot ! I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes..

Comment: Is `someString.utf8.count` computationally expensive? If I wanted to prevent a user from inputting text into a `UITextView` beyond a certain byte count (as opposed to character count), would it be rather expensive to call `textView.text.utf8.count` on every keystroke? Should I keep a running count outside of this computation to give the machine a break?

Comment: @kidcoder Don't try to optimize unless you actually have a performance problem.
Swift `String` has several types of internal representation and it can be actually already encoded as UTF8. Neverthless, counting UTF8 characters is not that complicated.