# Memory occupied by a string variable in swift

Tags: swift

I want to find the memory occupied by a string variable in bytes.
Lets suppose we have a variable named test

```
let test = "abvd"
```

I want to know how to find the size of test in runtime.

I have checked the details in [Calculate the size in bytes of a Swift String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335896/calculate-the-size-in-bytes-of-a-swift-string)

But this question is different.

According to apple, "Behind the scenes, Swift’s native String type is built from Unicode scalar values. A Unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number for a character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LATIN SMALL LETTER A ("a"), or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("")." This can be found in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

So if thats the case, apple is actually using a fixed size representation for unicode code points instead of the dynamic UTF8 encoding.

I wanted to verify this claim.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for the length of the string or the amount of memory used by the `String` variable reference?

Comment: @rmaddy the amount of memory used by the variable, not the length of the string

Comment: So the equivalent of `sizeof` from C/Objective-C.

Comment: @Murloc, this is not a duplicate of those; this question is about the memory held by `test`, not the length of the UTF-8 view of `test`. In some cases they may be the same. In other cases they can be very different (and there are no promises about it).

Comment: So the question/title leads to misunderstanding

Comment: Edited the question with more details

Comment: @rmaddy I agree that's closely related, but is going to give a confusing answer to this version of the question. It covers how to use `sizeof`, but not the fact that `sizeof` is almost certainly not the actual answer desired.

Comment: @RobNapier The OP's question isn't very clear. The updated question doesn't seem to match the OP's response to my first comment. My suggestion of the duplicate was based on their response to my comment. But I agree it doesn't seem to match their updated question.

Comment: not sur if is that what op need but :  MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: test)

Answer (score 6):

To your real goal: neither understanding is correct. Strings do not promise an internal representation. They can hold a variety of representations, depending on how they're constructed. In principle they can even take zero real memory if they are statically defined in the binary and memory mapped (I can't remember if the `StaticString` type makes use of this fully yet). The only way you're going to answer this question is to look at the current implementation, starting in [`String.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift), and then moving to [`StringCore.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift), and then reading the rest of the string files.

To your particular question, this is probably the beginning of the answer you're looking for (but again, this is *current* implementation; it's not part of any spec):

```
/// The core implementation of a highly-optimizable String that
/// can store both ASCII and UTF-16, and can wrap native Swift
/// _StringBuffer or NSString instances.
```

The end of the answer you're looking for is "it's complicated."

Note that if you ask for `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: test)`, you're going to get a surprising result (24), because that's just measuring the container. There is a reference type inside the container (which takes one word of storage for a pointer). There's no mechanism to determine "all the storage used by this value" because that's not very well defined when pointers get involved.

`String` only has one property:

```
var _core: _StringCore
```

And `_StringCore` has the following properties:

```
public var _baseAddress: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
var _countAndFlags: UInt
public var _owner: AnyObject?
```

Each of those take one word (8 bytes on a 64-bit platform) of storage, so 24 bytes total. It doesn't matter how long the string is.

Comment: @ssowri1 How much memory for what piece of it? Typically it's on the order of 2-bytes per character, plus overhead, but it depends and it's not promised to be implemented a specific way. (The Swift implementation just changed so many strings will require less memory, but still, that's not promised.)

Comment: @ssowri1 The first example would likely take no memory because it has either a short-string optimization or a static string optimization. The second (assuming you've made a typo and meant it to be `[NSMutableString alloc]`) would take something like 8 bytes plus some overhead (about 24 bytes last time I looked). But none of this is promised. What problem are you trying to address? You probably want to open a specific question in any case. You have an ObjC question and the comments on a Swift answer won't help other searchers.