# In Swift, how can I find the byte length of a UTF8 string within a larger buffer

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Data object with encoded UTF8 strings and other types of serialized values.  The first version of this question assumed that UTF8 had a built-in string termination, but it doesn't.

A chunk of UTF8 characters will have the same issues that a chunk of ascii bytes has.  The length of the string must be handled by either explicitly storing the length someplace, or by using a terminator (like NUL/0).

If you use a terminator, then you have to restrict the string contents so they do not contain the terminator value. This will then make your code not suitable for encoding all legal Swift Strings, but that may be okay depending on the application.

Comment: You can simply get the `str.utf8.count` property

Comment: So I guess, that `rawData` can be `someContenNULLsomeOtherContentNULL`? And you want to decode 2 stings from that, , decode and then remove `someContentNULL` from the buffer and continue? Then, what about finding NULL in `rawData`?

Comment: Swift strings can contain `NUL` bytes — the original approach here won't be sufficient, since you'll just get a single string with `NUL` bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the size in bytes of a Swift String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335896/calculate-the-size-in-bytes-of-a-swift-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Itai's answer is great, with lots of extra detail, but I wanted to create a short summary.

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
let buffer: Data = ...
let pos: Int = ...
let separator = UInt8(0x00)
let s = buffer[pos...].split(
    separator: separator,
    maxSplits: 1,
    omittingEmptySubsequences: false).map { 
        data in
        String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
    }[0]
pos += s.utf8.count + 1
```

Note:  If the buffer data has a single zero at the current location, it's important to use the omittingEmptySubsequences option so that an empty string is returned.

Note: Be careful of using Data.suffix.  It always creates a new Data object starting relative to the original *backing store*.  For example:

```
let data: Data = ...
let d1 = data.suffix(from: 10)
let d2 = d1.suffix(from: 10)
// d1 and d2 will have the same data.
```

That is why I chose to use the approach of keeping an integer location variable.

Comment: If you'd prefer to split the buffer in this way, you can also replace `split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)` with [`Data.prefix(while:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2832847-prefix), refined from [`Sequence.prefix(while:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3128810-prefix): `buffer[pos...].prefix(while: { $0 != separator })` will get you the range of bytes until the separator, without needing to treat the result like an array

Comment: In terms of performance, I would expect Data.prefix(while:) to be comparable with Data.split(maxSplits:1).  I don't think either one results in copying the bytes.  But I agree that in terms of readability, it's slightly better to use Data.prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Swift strings can contain `NUL` bytes (e.g. `"Hello\u{0000}world!"` is a valid `String`), so assuming your strings are terminated with `NUL` bytes, neither of your approaches would be sufficient.

Instead, you'll likely want to go with the approach that @Larme posted as a comment: split the data up first, and create strings from those slices.

If your separator is indeed a `NUL` byte, this can be as simple as

```
import Foundation

func decode(_ data: Data, separator: UInt8) -> [String] {
    data.split(separator: separator).map { String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self) }
}

let data = Data("Hello, world!\u{00}Following string.\u{00}And another one!".utf8)

print(decode(data, separator: 0x00))
// => ["Hello, world!", "Following string.", "And another one!"]
```

The `split(separator:)` method here is [`Sequence.split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3128818-split), which takes a separator of a single `Sequence.Element` — in this case, a single `UInt8`. `omittingEmptySubsequences` defaults to `true`, so

- If empty strings are valid inputs and you need to process them, make sure to pass in `false`. Otherwise,
- If your separator is `N` `NUL` bytes in a row, this method will still work for you: you'll get `N - 1` empty splits, all of which will be thrown away

Alternatively, if you don't want to eagerly split up the entire buffer up-front (e.g. you may be looking for a sentinel value which indicates to stop processing), you can split the buffer piecemeal by looping over the buffer and grabbing prefixes terminated by the separator using [`Data.prefix(while:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2832847-prefix):

```
import Foundation

func process(_ data: Data, separator: UInt8, using action: (String) -> Bool) {
    var slice = data[...]
    while !slice.isEmpty {
        let substring = String(decoding: slice.prefix(while: { $0 != separator }), as: UTF8.self)
        if !action(substring) {
            break
        }
        
        slice = slice.dropFirst(substring.utf8.count + 1)
    }
}

let data = Data("Hello, world!\u{00}Following string.\u{00}And another one!".utf8)
process(data, separator: 0x00) { string in
    print(string)
    return true // continue
}
```

---

If your separator is more complicated (e.g., multiple different characters long), you can still use `Data` methods to find instances of your separator sequence and split around them yourself:

```
import Foundation

func decode(_ data: Data, separator: String) -> [String] {
    // `firstRange(of:)` below takes a type conforming to `DataProtocol`.
    // `String.UTF8View` doesn't conform, but `Array` does. This copy should
    // be cheap if the separator is small.
    let separatorBytes = Array(separator.utf8)
    var strings = [String]()
    
    // Slicing the data will give cheap no-copy views into it.
    // This first slice is the full data blob.
    var slice = data[...]

    // As long as there's an instance of `separator` in the  data...
    while let separatorRange = slice.firstRange(of: separatorBytes) {
        // ... pull out all of the bytes before it into a String...
        strings.append(String(decoding: slice[..<separatorRange.lowerBound], as: UTF8.self))

        // ... and skip past the separator to keep looking for more.
        slice = slice[separatorRange.upperBound...]
    }
    
    // If there are no separators, in the string, or the last string is not
    // terminated with a separator itself, pull out the remaining contents.
    if !slice.isEmpty {
        strings.append(String(decoding: slice, as: UTF8.self))
    }
    
    return strings
}

let separator = "\u{00}\u{20}\u{00}"
let data = Data("Hello, world!\(separator)Following string.\(separator)And another one!".utf8)
print(decode(data, separator: separator))
// => ["Hello, world!", "Following string.", "And another one!"]
```

Comment: I think it's important to set omittingEmptySubsequences to false.  Having empty character strings seem like a common case and in my app I definitely need it.  So a zero byte at the start of the buffer has to be parsed as an empty string.

Comment: @ChrisQuenelle Good point, that's a completely valid use-case. Updated the answer to reflect that

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution

```
str.utf8.count
```

Comment: this is just a copy of @Leo Dabus comment from a few hours ago.

Comment: nope its working

Comment: @GopiDonga How do you know that without the OP's verification? Please [edit] in an explanation to improve your answer.

Comment: This is the approach I am leaning towards.  It's what I meant by solution #1 in my original question.  I don't know if the String implementation recalculates the UTF8 encoding in order to count the bytes.  It seems more efficient to remember the count when doing the conversion of UTF8 to String.

Comment: @ChrisQuenelle [`UTF8View.count`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8View.swift#L288) has a fast-path if the string is already backed by UTF-8 (an O(1) access) but otherwise, it would have to convert to UTF-8 every time to calculate. In your case, the string is guaranteed to be UTF-8, but if this were not the case ([`isContiguousUTF8`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3201133-iscontiguousutf8) were `false`), you needed the value more than once, and your strings were long, you would likely want to cache the result.