# How to add NSLinkAttributeName to emoji?

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, emoji, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to use emoji as a link.

```
emojiString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.google.com/" , range: NSMakeRange(0,1))
```

The code above turns the emoji into a link but the emoji will disappear.

Comment: Could it be because the emoji has a bigger length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775294/truncate-string-containing-emoji-or-unicode-characters-at-word-or-character-boun ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your issue may be this:

```
NSMakeRange(0,1)
```

Many Cocoa/Cocoa Touch APIs use UTF-16 based offsets & counts.

And most emojis are made of 2 UTF-16 code units, some others 4 or more.

If you want to make a range indicating the first character of `emojiString.string`, and make it a link, you may need to write something like this:

```
if let ch = emojiString.string.characters.first {
    let range = NSRange(0..<String(ch).utf16.count)
    emojiString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.google.com/" , range: range)
}
```